# Why is accessing myInstance.property1.subproperty2.subproperty3 costly in JavaScript but free in C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, performance

I have always understood it to be a cost-savings operation in JavaScript to avoid repeatedly referencing a nested property on an object. Instead of writing `a.b.c.d` over and over, you would favor `let x = a.b.c.d;` and then use `x` (what I've often heard colloquially called "caching the reference.")

It recently came up in conversation with a friend that such a thing would be completely unnecessary and foolish in C++.

Is that true? If so, why? I guess it has to do with the difference in the underlying language implementation between a C++ object and a JavaScript object, but what is the difference exactly?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects are closer to C++'s `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) than they are to C++ classes.

C++ has the advantage of having separate compilation and run steps.  The compiler can really take as long as it likes to analyze large chunks of your program and heavily optimize them.  When you're writing C++ you aren't really writing a program for the CPU to execute.  You're describing the behavior of a program and the compiler will use that description to come up with a program for you.  Your browser's JavaScript runtime (likely a JIT compiler) simply doesn't have the time to do the same level of analysis and optimization.  It has to compile and run your program quickly enough that users don't perceive any delay.  That's not to say a JavaScript runtime won't do *any* optimization, but it will tend to be more incremental and localized than what a C++ compiler that takes 20 minutes to compile a program can do.

All of the attributes of a C++ class are known at compile time.  When you access an attribute of an object in C++, the compiler will resolve that access at compile time; likely to a handful of memory loads or a single function call instruction.  Since it's all resolved at compile time, it doesn't matter how deeply an attribute lookup is nested.  The runtime performance will be the same.  Additionally, the compiler will do that sort of memorization for you, likely by keeping a repeatedly-accessed attribute in a register.

The same is not true of JavaScript.  JavaScript objects don't have a defined set of properties.  They can be added and removed throughout the lifetime of the object.  That means that the JavaScript runtime has to track an object's properties using some sort of associative data structure (likely a hash table).  When you request an attribute of an object, the runtime has to look through that data structure to find the value that you want, and it has to do that lookup for every level of nesting.